# How to authenticate user manually from cookie in laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel, cookies, laravel-5, session-variables

I am working on websockets, i am using [Rachet](http://socketo.me/). Whenever a user tries to establish a connection, i need to authenticate. My backend uses laravel 5 for all http authentification.

My server code is like this :

```
    public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn, RequestInterface $request = null) {
       if (null === $request) {
            throw new \UnexpectedValueException('$request can not be null');
       }
       $cookie = $request->getCookie('laravel_session'); 
//do authentification with cookie if possible
```

I tried to use laravel

```
Auth::user()
```

I got following error :

> Call to member function user() on null

Whenever i try to connect to websockets from browser, it will use ws protcol and rachets server, so laravel routes are never getting called. Is that the reason i am getting an error when i try to use `Auth::user()` ?

Can i use that cookie to verify if user is logged in? Is there any other solutions? What will be the security risks involved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got myself.

```
require_once getcwd() . '/bootstrap/autoload.php';
        $app = require getcwd() . '/bootstrap/app.php';

        $kernel = $app->make(\Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);
//        var_dump('kernel booted successfully');

        $response = $kernel->handle(
            $request = \Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
        );

//        var_dump('Response object created');

//        var_dump('Decrypting cookie : ');
//        var_dump($cookie);
        $id = $app['encrypter']->decrypt($cookie);

//        var_dump('Id decrypted : '.$id);
        $app['session']->driver()->setId($id);
        $app['session']->driver()->start();

        $user = $app['auth']->check();
        //if not logged in
        if( $user == false ){
            return false;
        }else{
             //return instance of an app
            return $app;
            //to get user details: $app['auth']->user()
        }
```